# Is it possible to schedule a destruction of an Azure VM?

Tags: azure

I deployed a spot VM on Azure, using an ephemeral OS Disk.

I also defined a [Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) resource with the hope to automatically shutdown (and so, in my case, destroy), the VM automatically:

```
resource autoShutdownConfig 'Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules@2018-09-15' = {
  name: 'shutdown-computevm-${vmName}'
  tags: mytags
  location: location
  properties: {
    status: 'Enabled'

    dailyRecurrence: {
      time: '02:00'
    }
    timeZoneId: 'UTC'
    taskType: 'ComputeVmShutdownTask'
    targetResourceId: vm.id
  }
}
```

However the shutdown task did not happen (instead I had an error in the activity log, at the time the task ran:)

> Operation 'deallocate' is not supported for VMs or VM Scale Set instances using an ephemeral OS disk.

I would like to know

- what values are available for `taskType` for a `Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules` resource
- if there is a `taskType` that can be used to destroy the VM at a specific time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Dev Test Lab schedules don't support destroying VM's, and as you saw you can't stop a VM/VMSS with an ephemeral disk you can only destroy it.

You could use Azure Automation to create a script that destroys the VM at a specific time. You would just need to write some azure PowerShell using the  `remove-azvm` command and then attach a schedule to the job to run at a specific time.